# json data insertion problem in postgresql database with python

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql, file

## main.py

```
data = []
with open('data.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
f.close()

fields = [
    'id', #integer
    'name', #varchar
    'log_date', #date
    'log_time', #timestamp
    'login', #timestamp
    'logout' #timestamp
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cur.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
```

[image: Error thorough]

## data.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Prosenjit Das",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": null,
        "logout": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sudipto Rahman",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": "11:26:45",
        "logout": "10:49:53"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Trump Khatun",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": null,
        "logout": null
    }
]
```

## postgresql column fields

[image: postgresql column fields]

My database connect is okay. In that picture line 37 when i'm using dumps instead of loads then another problem is shown in line 50 that "Typeerror: string indices must be integers".
Notice that here json format type is a list.
This kinds of problem but not exactly i've seen many but properly doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: the `json` is invalid because you have a trailing comma after the last object in the array, remove that comma and try reading it in again, also don't read in the `json` file line by line, just read it in all at once

Comment: Following on from @aws_apprentice, whenever working with `json` files, I like to paste the contents into https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to check that it is syntactically correct before running the program

Comment: @aws_apprentice Thanks. But this json data i'm getting from an API. So in this case can i remove comma after retrieve json data?

Comment: there is other problems here as well, specifically you need to specify which columns you are inserting given you are not uploading all the columns present in the table

Comment: @Prosenjit you'll have to modify it to conform to json standards otherwise it's not valid json

Comment: @aws_apprentice sorry that was not my real json data that's why something went wrong. I have checked my data given in your link and through valid json data. Tell me if you have another solution. Thanks.

Comment: please check out this following paste bin https://pastebin.com/DkVcNbmc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So couple of changes I would make here

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# no need to do f.close() since we are using a context manager

fields = [
    'id', #integer
    'name', #varchar
    'log_date', #date
    'log_time', #timestamp
    'login', #timestamp
    'logout' #timestamp
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[field] for field in fields]
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee (id, name, log_date, log_time, login, logout) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    # also ALL placeholders must be %s even if it is an integer
    cur.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
```

Also if you are using the `psycopg2` module for your DB actions you can do the following

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

my_data = [tuple(item[field] for field in fields) for item in data]
insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee (id, name, log_date, log_time, login, logout) VALUES %s"
execute_values(cursor, insert_query, my_data)
```

Comment: Sorry i haven't find yet trailing comma standard solution

Comment: you said that your json was valid and there was no trailing comma

Comment: yes that's showing valid. You can try that i've given above pastebin link my json data in that website that you gave me.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DkVcNbmc and https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ try please

Answer (score 0):

Load the json into a list of dicts once + removing an extra comma

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# now  you can iterate and push to entries to DB
```

data.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Prosenjit Das",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": null,
        "logout": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sudipto Rahman",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": "11:26:45",
        "logout": "10:49:53"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Trump Khatun",
        "log_date": "2019-03-02",
        "log_time": "12:10:12.247257",
        "login": null,
        "logout": null
    }, --> was removed
]
```

Comment: I've used that comma in the last but getting same output. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ in this site i've tested my json data https://pastebin.com/DkVcNbmc and showing valid. what happened here actually which comma i've to move i can't understand. Just you can check out my json data is valid or not.

Comment: Json looks fine. Do you still face any issue?

Comment: No. only i've faced that issue.